# Not able to connect to Excel as a database using Robotframework-databaselibrary

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to open a excel file as a database using the robot framework database library but i am not able to do that. Tried both the below keywords but getting several errors:

Connect To Database
Connect To Database Using Custom Params

Tried to google to find any example but couldn't find. Appreciate if someone can suggest if this is possible ? If yes, could you please suggest a correct way to call these keywords for excel file.

I have tried below:

1)

```
    *** Settings ***
    Library  DatabaseLibrary
    
    *** Test Cases ***
    Test1
        connect to database  excel  D:\TestFile.xlsx    ${EMPTY}    ${EMPTY}    ${EMPTY}    ${EMPTY}    ${EMPTY}    ${EMPTY}
    
    I have below db.cfg file as well:
    [default]
    dbapiModuleName=excel
    dbName=D:\\TestFile.xlsx
    dbUsername=
    dbPassword=
    dbHost=
    dbPort=
    
    This is giving error: NoSectionError: No section: 'default'
    
    2) 
    *** Settings ***
    Library  DatabaseLibrary
    
    *** Test Cases ***
    Test1
        connect to database using custom params  excel  database='D:\TestFile.xlsx', user='${EMPTY}', password='${EMPTY}', host='${EMPTY}', port='${EMPTY}'
    
    This is giving error: AttributeError: module 'excel' has no attribute 'connect'
    
    3) 
    *** Settings ***
    Library  DatabaseLibrary
    
    *** Test Cases ***
    Test1
        connect to database using custom params  pyodbc  database='D:\TestFile.xlsx', user='${EMPTY}', password='${EMPTY}', host='${EMPTY}', port='${EMPTY}'

This is giving below error: 

InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: Thanks @pavelsaman for your response. I have updated the questions with what I have done so far.